# Pass External Function into Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, directive

I'm struggling to find an elegant way of passing an external/out-of-scope/non angular function into a directive.  So far the only way I could see to do this was by passing the function name as a string into angular and then using eval which does not seem so nice.  Here is an example of that on Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/L9GGDkxwh4IGNufXB8yg?p=preview

Using extFunc:'&' in the scope only work for functions in the scope so that does not work for me.

Is there a better way of doing this?  I realise in my example one would just include the function inside the directive or controller but this is not always practical.

```
<script>
function nonAngularFunction( someText ) {
    alert( someText );
}
<script>

<my-directive ext-func="nonAngularFunction('Hi there')" ></my-directive>
```

Sorry if this question has already been asked but I could not find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd import this function in Angular's world as a service:

```
/* global nonAngularFunction:false */
angular.module('aModuleName', [])
    .value('nonAngularFunction', nonAngularFunction);
```

Then you can use injection and import the function to your scope:

```
// ... in your directive or controller
angular.module('maybeAnotherModule', ['aModuleName'])
    .controller('YourController', ['$scope', 'nonAngularFunction',
        function ($scope, nonAngularFunction) {

            $scope.nonAngularFunction = nonAngularFunction;
        }]);
```

Should work (I haven't tested it).

**Edit:** Alternative when there are dozens of external functions

`eval` is not a practical solution, since it doesn't have access to your scopes.

You could either import lots of your functions into Angular, e.g.

```
angular.module('aModuleName', [])
    .value('myHorribleLib', {
        'oneFunction': oneFunction,
        'Constructor1': Constructor1,
        ...
    });
```

Then you have to make them available by `$scope.legacyLib = myHorribleLib` and use it with a prefix: `ng-click="legacyLib.oneFunction('hello')"`. A bit verbose, but you keep your eyes of what is legacy.

Or you just extend `$rootScope` (or a top-level scope) with the methods:

```
angular.module('aModuleName', [])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$window', function ($rootScope, $window) {
        'oneFunction Constructor1 anotherFunction ...'
           .split(' ').forEach(function (f) {
               $rootScope[f] = $window[f];
           });
    }]);
```

I'm not saying this is a super-clean solution, but this way you could expose the functions of your legacy library to Angular scope. They should now work in normal `ng-click` and the like and have access to your scope.

Comment: The problem is I want this directive to be reusable within a site.  The angular code is to replace an older DevExpress (Which is horrific in every sence of the word) control.  There is a lot of existing javascript(non-angular) this needs to work with which is done differently in all uses of the old control.   I need to pass in trigger and callback functions.  Ideally this would go straight into the directive HTML and not require modification of the application or directive code.